# Need these styled panels to change color after data entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, electron

So, working for my universities research group, I am creating a program with a GUI which will be automating the growth processes of an Atomic Layer Deposition system. I have a panel called "Heating" with an edit button, when you click edit it takes you to another page with 12 other panels for the 12 different heating zones. These zones have input fields to set your desired temperatures, and I am wanting these panels/boxes to change color after you have put in a temperature within the correct parameters.
So, say you can only put in temps between 50-120 Celsius, if user enters "115" I want the panel to turn green, if user enters "40" I want the panel to turn red.
Also, I want the main "heating" panel which contains these 12 panels, to change color once the temps have been reached.
What would be the best way to go about this? I am no expert programmer, we are using Electron, HTML, CSS, JS, and Vue.JS to create this program

These are 2 Screenshots of program, on the 1st you can see the panel labeled "Heating" and on the 2nd image you can see the 12 zones labeled 1-14.

**One:**

[image: screenshot one]

**Two:**

[image: screenshot two]

Comment: "*I am no expert programmer, we are using Electron, HTML, CSS, JS, and Vue.JS to create this program*" - You're using all these things and none of you know how to set a min/max on a box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

Use a number input box (`<input type='number'>`) with

- `min`: The minimum of the range
- `max`: The maximum of the range
- `value`: value to start with.
- `required`: can't be empty

---

```
<input id="temp" type="number" value="1" min="0" max="100" required>
```

---

You can then use CSS selectors (`input:valid` and `input:invalid`) to adjust the input box itself or to adjust a sibling element like a `span`:

---

### Examples:

**With Sibling Span**:

```css
input:invalid + span:after {
  content: '✖';
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: red;
}

input:valid + span:after {
  content: '✓';
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
    <label for="temp">Temp between 0 and 100:</label>
    <input id="temp" type="number" value="1" min="0" max="100" required>
    <span></span>
```

---

**With Input Styling**:

---

```css
input {
padding: 10px;
font-weight: bolder;
font-size:1.3em;
font-family: monospace;
border: dashed 3px black;
width: 30%;
text-align: center;
}
input:invalid {
  background: rgba(100,0,0,.3);
  color: black;
}

input:valid {
background: rgba(0, 200,0,.3);
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<label for="temp">Temp between 0 and 100:</label>
    <input id="temp" type="number" value="1" min="0" max="100" required>
    <span></span>
```

Comment: Thank you! And I simply haven't had to do this before, that's why I was unaware of how to complete this. Simple enough to do. I'm a senior at my university, and I'm not even a CompSci major. I am in electrical & computer engineering, I joined the research team and they needed help with this, so I've practically been learning these languages/platforms on the fly. thanks for your help